# R: lme, cannot evaluate groups for desired levels on 'newdata'

Tags: r, statistics, nlme

I'm running an `lme` -model from the package `nlme` on R v.3.0.2.
I'm trying to extract the model estimates with `predict.lme`, but it returns an error. Here's the code to replicate the error:

```
my.model = lme(fixed = Maxi ~ Time*Origin, random = ~ 1 |Genotype, method = "REML", weights=varPower(), data=dd)
new.my.model <-  data.frame(Origin = c("Ka", "Ka", "La", "La"), Time = c("mor", "eve", "mor", "eve"))
predict(my.model, new.my.model, level = 0:1)
#Error in predict.lme(my.model, new.my.model, level = 0:1) : 
#cannot evaluate groups for desired levels on 'newdata'
```

and here's the data:

```
dd<-read.table(text="Origin Genotype  Time Maxi
Ka    Ka1     mor 14,59
Ka    Ka1     eve 13,42
Ka    Ka11    mor 14,08
Ka    Ka11    eve 16,29
Ka    Ka15    mor 14,38
Ka    Ka15    eve 14,56
La    La1     mor 17,82
La    La1     eve 13,28
Ka    Ka1     mor 16,44
Ka    Ka1     eve 15,52
Ka    Ka15    mor 13,76
Ka    Ka15    eve 13,55
Ka    Ka1     mor 19,15
Ka    Ka1     eve 19,12
La    La6     mor 10,54
La    La6     mor 11,38
La    La6     eve 10,48
Ka    Ka15    mor 15,25
Ka    Ka15    eve 16,51
La    La1     mor 17,46
La    La1     eve 15,57
Ka    Ka1     mor 16,83
Ka    Ka1     eve 15,63
Ka    Ka15    mor 14,54
Ka    Ka15    eve 15,09
La    La1     mor 11,3
La    La1     eve 11,94", header=TRUE, dec=",")
```

Data is two factors (Ka, La) with two levels each (mor, eve) and a random effect. I'm trying to extract the estimates for the 4 levels of data, i.e. Ka,mor ; Ka,eve ; La,mor ; La,eve.

First asked over at CV in another context, but I was recommended here.

Comment: You need to specify a value for Genotype in your newdata parameter since Genotype is in your model. You could do `new.my.model  <-data.frame(expand.grid(Origin=c("Ka","La"), Time=c("mor","eve")), Genotype="Ka1")`

Comment: This would return: `Error in sprintf(ngettext(sum(wch), "level %s not allowed for %s", "levels %s not allowed for %s"),  : 
  too few arguments.` Did I do something wrong? Besides, not really interested in the random effect, I just need the 4 means. Wouldn't this also return something for the Genotypes? Btw is this the only way to extract the estimates in `nlme`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore the random component, then setting `levels=0:1` is not correct; you should just use `levels=0`.

```
new.my.model <- expand.grid(Origin=c("Ka","La"), Time=c("mor","eve"))
( pm<-predict(my.model, new.my.model, level = 0) )

# [1] 15.30408 15.51259 12.99398 12.05721
# attr(,"label")
# [1] "Predicted values"

cbind(new.my.model, pred.mean=pm)

#   Origin Time pred.mean
# 1     Ka  mor  15.30408
# 2     La  mor  12.99398
# 3     Ka  eve  15.51259
# 4     La  eve  12.05721
```

Comment: This works well and you're exactly right. Thanks for everything. Noticed my error on my own as well, and I also had another stupid bug. Should I close this question or leave as a reference? BTW If I did want the random component, it seems I would have to make a lengthy argument for `new.my.model` which seems like a hassle in many cases, or is there an easy way? Also note that `Ka` and `La` Genotypes are only within `Ka` and `La` Origins, respectively, wouldn't your first suggestion give estimates for Ka for both origins? Oh and I had another question, is there a way to also get the std.errors?

Comment: I'm not sure which "lengthy argument" for new.my.model you would need. My comment on your original question showed a way to include a genotype value. If you have a new question, then you should start a new post so other can answer rather than asking new questions in the comments.